# Optimizing Datetime searches in huge MySQL InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, datetime, optimization, indexing, innodb

I am trying to optimize a big MySQL InnoDB Table with 50 million rows in it. It is a kind of a log. Each row contains some columns with information and a Datetime column.

These 50 million rows contain only 5-6 dates, so there are only a few distinct dates but with different hours, minutes and seconds. Each row has a unique ID (primary key). The DateTime column has an index.

The searches are performed with the only date (w/o using hours, minutes, and sec), f.e.

```
select * from table where date(datetime_column) = '2021-03-08'
```

I've already tried to rewrite the queries without date() function, like:

```
select * from table where datetime_column >= '2021-03-08' and datetime_column <='2021-03-08 23:59:59'
```

But it's only a bit faster.

Also, I've created a new table, put the ID (primary key from the main table), year, month, day, hour, minutes, and seconds to tyniints (the year is int(4)), made a combined index on them and performed the select from the main table with join to this new table, but it's still not fast enough, because index for hours, minutes and seconds become useless while these columns are not mentioned in the "where" clause.

Also, I've thought about partitioning, but I think it won't help too.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Have you confirmed the index is used by analyzing the query with `EXPLAIN`? If there are only a few distinct dates, and a given date might match 20% or more of the rows, then the optimizer might choose not to use the index anyway.

Comment: What is your most common query? Is it really `select * from table where column = a date`? On an average, each day seems to have 10 million records. Selecting 10 million records for a given day is going to take time.

Comment: When the date() function is used - the indexes are skipped. And when I run the query without date() - the index on Datetime filed works fine. But the problem that it's almost useless, because only 5-6 different days in the table with many different hours/minutes/seconds, so the query without mentioning hours/minutes/seconds take almost the same time as queries with date() function (without index at all)

Comment: zedfoxus, yes, I've simplified the query, there are some where clauses more, but in general yes - queries like where column = a date, or column between ... . When I delete all other where clauses from the query except datetime - the speed stays almost the same.

Comment: Please add to your question: (1) the actual query, not a simplified query, so we can see the other `WHERE` clause terms, (2) the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we see your columns, data types, and indexes, and (3) the result of `EXPLAIN` analyzing your actual query.

Comment: How much RAM?  How big is the table?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Show a few of the most common queries; it will devise the best set of indexes for all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX(datetime)
```

to

```
PRIMARY KEY(datetime, id),  -- to greatly speed up your range query
INDEX(id)   -- sufficient to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

Do not use the `DATE(datetime) = constant`; it cannot use any index.  Your other attempt can use an index in some situations.  I like this way to phrase it:

```
WHERE datetime >= '2021-03-08'
  AND datetime  < '2021-03-08' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Oh, you say there is more to the WHERE?  Let's see them; it may make a big difference!  Also, let us know whether the datetime range does most of the filtering or the other clause(s) do more.

Many queries look something like

```
WHERE datetime in some range AND abc=123
```

That benefits from `INDEX(abc, datetime)`, *in that order*.  Pulling the PK trick above *may* also be beneficial:  `PRIMARY KEY(abc, datetime, id), INDEX(id)`.

Comment: Putting the datetime to the primary key first helped a lot. Also I've made partitioning by date and got what I've needed. Thank you!